# Are there solutions to boot to a hidden OS only when special usb key is present?

Tags: boot, yubikey, honeypot

My laptop was stolen recently.
Unfortunately I did not take the time to install a honeypot on it.
With my new laptop I am thinking about installing a honeypot OS and a hidden OS that I will use for my actual computing.
I would like to achieve that my laptop would go to the honeypot if no yubi key is present.
With the key inserted, it would boot into the private OS.
I had a similar setup before, but every time I forgot to select the private OS in my bootloader, I would end up in the honeypot OS and had to restart.

I would like to use Windows for the honeypot and private OS.

Can anyone point me to the right direction here?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I would prefer to use windows home or pro.

Comment: You can add your main OS as additional (nondefault) entry in the UEFI boot manager. Then you could boot into it by pressing the key that opens the UEFI boot manager (depends on BIOS; typically F2, F12 or Del) and selecting the correct entry. If the key is not pressed UEFI will boot the default entry (-> the honeypot OS). The only problem may arise when you install system updates because all OS mostly rewrite the UEFI boot order so that the are the default entry.